# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern - linq error

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

Having trouble with my linq query in my model of MVC. I have an edmx which is composed of ObjectSet and EntityObject. this is where im getting the error "from c in **CanaClie0012**". when i go to definition it is going to my entityObject.

```
   public class ClientRepository
    {

        public List<ClientSearchResult> Search(ClientSearchFilter filter, string sortColumn, string sortOrder, int pageSize, int pageIndex, out int totalRecords)
        {

            var q = from c in CanaClie0012
                    select new ClientSearchResult
                    {
                        Client00130012 = c.Client00130012,
                        F1Pais00200012 = c.F1Pais00200012,
                        F1Cana02530012 = c.F1Cana02530012,
                        Direcc0012 = c.Direcc0012,
                    };

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Client00130012))
            {
                q = q.Where(c => c.Client00130012.ToLower().Contains(filter.Client00130012.ToLower()));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.F1Pais00200012))
            {
                q = q.Where(c => c.F1Pais00200012.ToLower().Contains(filter.F1Pais00200012.ToLower()));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.F1Cana02530012))
            {
                q = q.Where(c => c.F1Cana02530012.ToLower().Contains(filter.F1Cana02530012.ToLower()));
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Direcc0012))
            {
                q = q.Where(c => c.F1Cana02530012.ToLower().Contains(filter.F1Cana02530012.ToLower()));
            }


            switch (sortColumn)
            {
                case "Client00130012":
                    q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.Client00130012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.Client00130012);
                    break;
                case "F1Pais00200012":
                    q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.F1Pais00200012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.F1Pais00200012);
                    break;
                case "Direcc0012":
                    q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.Direcc0012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.Direcc0012);
                    break;
                case "F1Cana02530012":
                    q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.F1Cana02530012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.F1Cana02530012);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            totalRecords = q.Count();
            return q.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        }


    }
```

I have already tried adding this:

```
List<CanaClie0012> clients = new List<CanaClie0012>();
```

But its returning null values. Kindly help me. Im lost here.

Comment: What is `CanaClie0012`, what is the declaration of that identifier?

Comment: `CanaClie0012` wouldn't seem to be an `Enumerable<T>` or `Queryable<T>`.

Comment: public partial class CanaClie0012 : EntityObject                   public ObjectSet<CanaClie0012> CanaClie0012                                    These are its declaration in the model.designer.cs

Comment: its name is also 'CanaClie0012'. should I change its name? @GertArnold

Comment: No, not necessarily (although it would help to tell them apart). But I would expect something like `from c in context.CanaClie0012`. Could you "zoom out" a bit an show the code around your query? (By editing your question).

Comment: So the issue changed? Maybe you should change the title and the last 3 sentences.

Comment: i revert it back to the previous issue. i forgot i changed it when i edited it.

Comment: Well, `clients.CanaClie0012` made a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right @Gert Arnold. that did solve my problem.. thank you.

```
  MMProdatEntities clients = new MMProdatEntities();

            public List<ClientSearchResult> Search(ClientSearchFilter filter, string sortColumn, string sortOrder, int pageSize, int pageIndex, out int totalRecords)
            {

                var q = from c in clients.CanaClie0012
                        join d in clients.Clientes0013 on c.Client00130012 equals d.Client0013 
                        select new ClientSearchResult
                        {
                            Client00130012 = c.Client00130012,
                            F1Pais00200012 = c.F1Pais00200012,
                            F1Cana02530012 = c.F1Cana02530012,
                            Direcc0012 = c.Direcc0012,
                        };

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Client00130012))
                {
                    q = q.Where(c => c.Client00130012.ToLower().Contains(filter.Client00130012.ToLower()));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.F1Pais00200012))
                {
                    q = q.Where(c => c.F1Pais00200012.ToLower().Contains(filter.F1Pais00200012.ToLower()));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.F1Cana02530012))
                {
                    q = q.Where(c => c.F1Cana02530012.ToLower().Contains(filter.F1Cana02530012.ToLower()));
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Direcc0012))
                {
                    q = q.Where(c => c.Direcc0012.ToLower().Contains(filter.Direcc0012.ToLower()));
                }


                switch (sortColumn)
                {
                    case "Client00130012":
                        q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.Client00130012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.Client00130012);
                        break;
                    case "F1Pais00200012":
                        q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.F1Pais00200012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.F1Pais00200012);
                        break;
                    case "F1Cana02530012":
                        q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.F1Cana02530012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.F1Cana02530012);
                        break;
                    case "Direcc0012":
                        q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.Direcc0012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.Direcc0012);
                        break;
                    default:
                        q = (sortOrder == "desc") ? q.OrderByDescending(c => c.Client00130012) : q.OrderBy(c => c.Client00130012);
                        break;
                }
                totalRecords = q.Count();

                return q.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            }
```